# Avoid caching problems when creating an edit form with vue-apollo

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo

I'm working on my first vue-apollo project and I'm wondering what's the best way to create an edit form. I can't seem to find any examples online.

Right now I'm querying my user data like this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
      },
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    user: {
      query: USER_QUERY,
    },
  },
}
```

With a simple form like this:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="user.name" />

  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="user.email" />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I edit the form and then close it, my edit is returned by the GraphQL cache when I return to the form. This is because my input is binded directly to the object returned by my GraphQL query with v-model. I can think of a two things to avoid this:

- Create a copy of the data returned by the query (and call it user and userData?), and bind the v-model to the keys of that object. But it bugs me that I need to create a duplicate variable and have the data in two places.
- Or disable cache for this GraphQL query altogether.

It feels like I'm missing a more obvious solution. When I was using REST a had a Form class handing all form interactions based on this:

https://medium.com/@jeffochoa/vuejs-laravel-object-oriented-forms-f971cb50b7ab

Maybe it can be solved in a similar way? What is you preferred method of building an (edit) form with Vue/Apollo/GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only tell you my preferred way. At it's most basic I do something like this...

**UserForm.vue**

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="proposedName" />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
</template>

<script>
import MyUserQuery from '/wherever/MyUserQuery.gql'
import MyUserMutation from '/wherever/MyUserMutation.gql'

export default {
  data() {
    return: {
      proposedName: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      this.$apollo.mutate({
        mutation: MyUserMutation,
        variables: {
          name: this.proposedName
        }
      })

      this.proposedName = ''
    }
  },

  apollo: {
    user: {
      query: MyUserQuery,
      result({data}) {
        this.proposedName = data.user.name
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My `proposedVariable` thing is wordy, but I find it keeps me from confusing form data and Apollo data. I'm sure other people have other strategies.

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen for a similar approach in the end!

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript** objects are stored as a **reference**. When you assign the object to another variable, you're just assigning the **memory address** of the object to that variable.

> So, in the result object, you should avoid direct assignment and use JSON.parse like:

```
this.proposedName = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.user.name))
```